# Issue while using contextmenu with listview items in a popupwindow

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, popupwindow, onitemselectedlistener

I am developing an android application, my proposal is have two clickable textviews on the page and when user press each of the textview, a listview in a popupwindow will shows under the textview, when user choose a listview item, the textview will be setText() as the name as user selected, when user perform long click on the textview or on the listview item, a contextmenu can be shown to allow user "edit"(jump to a new activity for that) or "delete" the selected item and after that the list adapter can update the list accordingly.
I have finished the code of registerContextMenu for the textview and it works, but the context menu won't show after I added the same code to the listview, I also tried add OnCreateContextMenuListener to the listview but failed again. can any expert help to look into this? thanks a lot. 
here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnCreateContextMenuListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

/**
 * @author Allen
 * 
 *
 */
public class ProfileActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView aTextView;
    private TextView bTextView;
    private View popupWindow;
    // to initial popupwindow width and height
    private final int popupWindowWidth = 400;
    private final int popupWindowHeight = 350;

    // the background drawable for popupWindow
    ColorDrawable blackBackground = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK);

    private PopupWindow aPW;
    private ListView aListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> aListViewAdapter;

    private List<String> popupNameList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile_page);
        init();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Long press item to modify", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void init() {
        aTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aSelectionTextView);
        aTextView.setText("Pls select");
        aTextView.getPaint().setFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
        //to bTextView will be the same process, only the popupnamelist //will be the different list
        popupNameList = new ArrayList<String>();

        popupWindow = this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.profile_popup_window, null);

        aPW = new PopupWindow(popupWindow, popupWindowWidth, popupWindowHeight);

        addOnClickListeners();

    }

    private void aSelection() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        popupNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
        popupNameList.add("abc");
        popupNameList.add("ABC");
        popupNameList.add("123");

        // to enable the outside click dismiss the PW
        aPW.setBackgroundDrawable(blackBackground);
        aPW.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        // to limit dispatching the click event.
        aPW.setFocusable(true);

        aListView = (ListView) popupWindow.findViewById(R.id.profile_popup_lstview);
        aListViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.profile_listview_item, popupNameList);
        aListView.setAdapter(aListViewAdapter);

        aListView.setLongClickable(true);

        this.registerForContextMenu(aListView);

        aListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                aTextView.setText(popupNameList.get(position));
                aPW.dismiss();
            }
        });

        aListView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(mListOnCreateContextMenuListener);

    }

    private void addOnClickListeners() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        aTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                aSelection();
                aPW.showAsDropDown(findViewById(R.id.aSelectionTextView), 0, -10, Gravity.START);
            }
        });

        this.registerForContextMenu(aTextView);
    }

    public void onLaunchDoneClick(View view) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        // menu.setHeaderTitle("Operation");
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, getString(R.string.edit));
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, getString(R.string.delete));

    }

    private final OnCreateContextMenuListener mListOnCreateContextMenuListener = new OnCreateContextMenuListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onCreateContextMenu()", 1000).show();
            menu.add(0, 0, 0, getString(R.string.edit));
            menu.add(0, 1, 0, getString(R.string.delete));
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 0:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), popupNameList.get(menuInfo.position), 1000).show();
            aListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        case 1:
            break;

        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;

    }

}
```

The layout xml is here:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bSelectionTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/aSelectionTextView"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/aSelectionTextView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/aSelectionTextView"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:text="BSelectionTextView"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/okButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/dSelectionTextView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/my_button_style"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onLaunchDoneClick"
            android:text="@string/Done"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:text="ASelection"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:text="BSelection"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/aSelectionTextView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:text="ASelectionTextView"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can anybody help to look into this issue? thanks a lot!!!

Comment: this issue still there, hope can get your guidance to fix it. thanks.

Comment: It's disappointed that no one can help on this, any idea on how this happens are welcome to discuss. thanks